# Redirect (POST) to external URL with parameters and get its response on JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am trying to pass my application data to the third party **URL** (POST)

Application is based upon Simple JSP-Servlet and m using **sendRedirect("URL+param")**

Its working for now, but its landing page? after completing process from URL-page i want to display its response on my application page.
[image: Something like]

This ll looks like this.

And i want to handle 1st and 3rd process in my application.

Comment: Why not post it using ajax? Use javascript to get the contents of the form, and post them to the server using ajax. Then, you can read the response, and display it in any way you like on your page.

Comment: @stripybadger Yes but i want like_ when we are at online-Shopping process its redirecting to Payment_form(from Bank) page to fill card info. after completing it back to our form.

Comment: @V.Rohan, the third party payment pages I've worked with require you to configure a redirect url through your account with them.  You have to tell their application to redirect users back to you after paying.

Answer (score 1):

If You are going to receive response from that third application not basing on 1st process then you can get the response by including that responding page in your application. If 3rd process is relevant to your 1st process then you must have access to change the code in third party app.